# To show a function which is analytic in disk and attains minimum is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is analytic on the disk $\{z/ |z-4| \lt 6\}$ and |f| attains it's minimum at $z=2+3i$ then show that $f(2+3i)=0$ or $f$ is constant .

I think I have to draw the region where the function is analytic and then use some results to show that it is constant. 
Any help is welcomed

Comment: Please learn to typeset the math properly. You've been around MSE long enough to know that.

Comment: It is easy once you know holomorphic functions are analytic. If $f(z)$ is analytic and non-constant then as $z\to z_0$  : $f(z)∼f(z_0)+C(z−z0)^n$ for some $n$ and $C\ne 0$ so that $z_0$ can't be a local maximum of $|f|$ –